# Is assuming the constant speed of light the wrong way to postulate Special Relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

Including that as a postulate gives the impression that the universe "wants" every observer to see light moving at the same speed, and to do that it bends all the rules about length and time. That's not really true though from what I've heard. What I've heard is that the universe would be the same way even if there was nothing that moved at light speed. If that's true then I think a more insightful way to formulate Special Relativity would be to have more basic postulates and then arrive at the constant speed of light as a consequence. It'd be so that the theory wouldn't have to rely on the constant speed of light.

Comment: It works; what is your definition of "wrong"?  Why should your "insight" convince us?  What have you "heard"?  It appears that you are attempting to run before you are able to crawl.

Comment: What would you do instead? If Maxwell had not _predicted_ that the speed of light was the same constant value for all observers, then what would have motivated anybody to even _wonder_ about a "theory of relativity?"

Comment: @m4r35n357 It does give the correct results, yes. But it's like postulating that the length of a rod is equal to the length of its shadow divided by the cosine of the angle with the vertical. It works numerically, but the shadow is a consequence of the rod length instead of the other way around.

Comment: @RyderRude All this mental contortionism to avoid the postulates or consequences of special relativity is harder than just learning it, I swear.  Once you have learned it, you might not be motivated so much to find fault.  There are derivations that start from another POV, which "deduce" that there is a maximum speed, c.  Like this https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s1-07/1-07.htm  This page is in line with the accepted answer.

Comment: @mrr35n357 I'm not trying to avoid learning it. I understand that even if there are other method of derivation, they are probably too advanced and that I am better off learning it the standard way. I posted this to know if other derivation which didn't rely on the constant speed of light existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although treatments of special relativity usually take the speed of light to be a postulate, it is not logically necessary to do so. We can derive the special theory simply from one postulate, the general principle of relativity, taken together with observations to reject discrete alternatives, and the constraint that it applies locally, in inertial reference frames.

- **The general principle of relativity:** Local laws of physics are the same irrespective of the reference matter which a particular observer uses to quantify them.

Either there is, or there is not, a maximum speed in nature. If there were not, the laws of physics would be different from those we observe. Therefore there is a maximum speed, and according to the general principle it is the same for all observers.

The mathematical form of special relativity depends only on the existence of a maximum speed. It just happens that, to the accuracy of measurement, light travels at the maximum speed.

Answer (score 0):

Special relativity is based on two postulates:

- All the inertial reference frames are equivalent
- The speed of light is the same in all these reference frames
  Everything else are mathematical developments.

One can build a theory with other assumptions, but it will not be special relativity. Note also that the constancy of the speed of light is an established experimental fact.